# Visualization of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can I find the image of a rectangle

> $$a<\Re(z)<b \\c<\Im(z)<d$$

under the function $z^3$ , I tried breaking up $z$ into $x+iy$ and cubing it. I got the real and imaginary parts but how can I plot the function under given domain.

Comment: Try to parameterise the boundary
$$\{a = \Re z, c \leq \Im z \leq d\} \cup \{b = \Re z, c \leq \Im z \leq d\} \cup \ldots$$
And then find the image of the boundary curve.

Comment: Consider two cases: the rectangle contains the origin or not.

Comment: It is for a general case.(might contain origin or might not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi_i(t) : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}, \quad i = 1..4$ be defined by
$$\begin{align*}\phi_1(t) & = (b-a)t + a + ci\\
\phi_2(t) & = b + ((d-c)t + c)i \\
\phi_3(t) & = (a-b)t + b + di \\
\phi_4(t) & = a + ((c-d)t + d)i
\end{align*}$$
Then $\phi: [0,4] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\phi(t-k) = \phi_{k+1}(t)$ for suitable $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ is a parameterisation of the boundary of your rectangle.

---

Can you figure out the rest?

Comment: I was thinking abt writing z as x+iy then cubing it and then putting x as constant and varying y(image of vertical line) which is equivalent to putting x=a and writing y as t (same as yours but your parameterizaton is more accurate). But when I try eliminating t the eqn of curve is getting too complicated. I am getting degree 3 terms in x and degree 2 terms in y. I am not able to visualize the curve.(Or am I doing something wrong).

Comment: Visualize by plotting $(\Re \phi^3(t), \Im \phi^3(t))$ for $t\in[0,4]$ (or, equivalently for $\phi_i, t\in[0,1]$ and $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: What if the function is $C \rightarrow C$?

Comment: @qed You can do several different types of plots then, for example plotting $z = {\rm abs}(\Phi(x+iy))$ and coloring the surface according to ${\rm arg}(\Phi(x+iy))$